# Set part of a lambda function in advance to avoid repeated code

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following sorting method works perfectly.

```py
def sort_view_items(self):

    cs = self.settings.case_sensitive

    if self.settings.sort_by_file_name:
        sk = lambda vi: (vi.name if cs else vi.name.lower(), vi.group, vi.tab)

    elif self.settings.sort_by_folder:
        sk = lambda vi: (vi.folder, vi.name if cs else vi.name.lower())

    elif self.settings.sort_by_syntax:
        sk = lambda vi: (vi.syntax, vi.name if cs else vi.name.lower())

    elif self.settings.sort_by_indexes:
        sk = lambda vi: (vi.group, vi.tab)

    self.view_items.sort(key = sk)
```

However the case sensitive related section of the lambdas `vi.name if cs else vi.name.lower()` gets used 3 times which irks my repeated code gene.

Out of interest, can the case aspect be set in advance somehow, but without making permenant changes to the `name` attribute or doing so in a temporary copy of the `view_items` list?

For example I tried using a lambda within a lambda which I didn't think would work and, guess what, it didn't. Although unexpectedly the syntax was accepted (no exceptions), it just didn't result in any sorting being actually performed.

```py
def sort_view_items(self):

    cs = self.settings.case_sensitive

    name_lambda = lambda vi: vi.name if cs else vi.name.lower()

    if self.settings.sort_by_file_name:
        sk = lambda vi: (name_lambda, vi.group, vi.tab)

    ...
```

Comment: Note that defining a `lambda` and assigning it to a name like that defeats the whole purpose of `lambda` functions, and is specifically cautioned against in PEP-8.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Are you referring to my "lambda within a lambda" code or to the whole `sk = lambda vi: (vi.name if cs else vi.name.lower(), vi.group, vi.tab)` code?

Comment: It's a little more efficient to define your key functions outside `sort_view_items`. When you define functions inside another function those inner functions get re-compiled every time you call the outer function.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks that's useful to know, but in this particular case `sort_view_items()` only gets called once.

Comment: Ah, rightio. In that case, what you're doing is fine. :) Although as Tigerhawk said, lambdas are _supposed_ to be anonymous, and you should use a proper `def` function if you don't want an anonymous function, although I'll concede that this is a borderline case.

Comment: @PM2Ring I'm still unclear as to whether you and Tigerhawk are referring to my original method, posted below "The following sorting method works perfectly", or to the code which uses a "lambda within a lambda"?

Comment: @mattst. Both. According to the PEP-8 style guide, if you create an anonymous function and the give it a name, you're doing it wrong. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations

Comment: @PM2Ring So PEP8 recommends [this](https://gist.github.com/mattst/bc33fb9b337ea27a088815278d265c9c) over [this](https://gist.github.com/mattst/a3d24f52885b452f0689c1b91be95743) (which I think is much more readable). Or am I missing another approach?

Comment: @mattst You can use a `def` statement where you are currently assigning the result of a `lambda` expression to a name (`def sk(vi): return ...` instead of `sk = lambda vi: ...`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to actually call `name_lambda`:

```
sk = lambda vi: (name_lambda(vi), vi.group, vi.tab)
```

In your snippet, `name_lambda` is defined correctly but it is never going to be called.

Answer (score 5):

This requires you to add a new property, "lower_name", to your class, but this one change lets you *greatly* simplify the rest of the code.

```
from operator import attrgetter

class Things(object):
    @property
    def lower_name(self):
        return self.name.lower()

    def sort_view_items(self):
        name_field = "name" if self.settings.case_sensitive else "lower_name"

        if self.settings.sort_by_file_name:
            fields = (name_field, "group", "tab")
        elif self.settings.sort_by_folder:
            fields = ("folder", name_field)
        elif self.settings.sort_by_syntax:
            fields = ("syntax", name_field)
        elif self.settings.sort_by_indexes:
            fields = ("group", "tab")

        self.view_items.sort(key=attrgetter(*fields))
```

Comment: You should name your name (in the first line of sort_view_items) `name_field` to be consistent with the rest of the code. Otherwise, great usage of attrgetter. And _please_ use `.casefold` for casefolding instead of `.lower` (if your Python is new enough).

Comment: Thanks for the bug fix, and good suggestion for using `casefold` if available.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to use it in 3 of 4 conditions, the best way for refusing of this repetition, is computing the name at the top of your `if` conditions. Also You can use a `def` key word to create your `key` function properly, and return the corresponding value, istead of defining a function each time. In this case you can pass the `vi` to `key_func` and calculate the `name` the the top level of this function.

```
def sort_view_items(self):

    def key_func(vi):
        name = vi.name if self.settings.case_sensitive else vi.name.lower()
        if self.settings.sort_by_file_name:
            return name(vi), vi.group, vi.tab

        elif self.settings.sort_by_folder:
            return vi.folder,name(vi)

        elif self.settings.sort_by_syntax:
            return vi.syntax, name(vi)

        elif self.settings.sort_by_indexes:
            return vi.group, vi.tab

    self.view_items.sort(key=key_func)
```

Comment: That throws an exception: `NameError: global name 'vi' is not defined`

Comment: @mattst Yeah, that's because you don't have `vi` in your function name space, let me update!

Comment: Also that's less efficient, since it has to do all those `if` / `elif` tests for _every_ key.

Comment: @PM2Ring As I said, since we need the name in 3 of 4, it's reasonable to do this but still it's not a proper way to go, check out my last update for the more pythonic way.

Comment: Your latest update still performs the if / elif tests for every element in the list being sorted. Of course, it may not perform all 4 tests, as it stops as soon as a test condition is True. But still...